# Javascript: Regex case insensitive

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex expression being used in a JavaScript function.

```
regex = /(([a-zA-Z]{3})+([0-9]{12})+(.zip))$/g;
```

I want the last characters (.zip) also as case insensitive. How to achieve this ?
Thanks

Comment: `/(([a-z]{3})+([0-9]{12})+(\.zip))$/gi`

Answer (score 2):

Use i modifier

```js
var regex = /(([a-z]{3})+([0-9]{12})+(\.zip))$/ig; 
var str="abAc772345678989.ZIP";
console.log(regex.test(str))
```

Comment: Why not use the `i` flag simply? Also, the `.` before the `zip` in the regex will match any character except newline. Not just `.`

Comment: OP says "case-insensitive" so to be thorough, you'd need to handle "ZiP", "zIP", "ZIp", etc